# Android CoordinatorLayout shows duplicated App Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Basically I created an Activity with a CoordinatorLayout, everything seems to be working. But there is 2 AppBars. One is empty (no text) and is shown on top of the activity. While the other one behaves as it should on the coordinator layout: initially just text, no background; and as you slide up it move to the top of the screen, and it gains a background (if this sounds confusing just look at the animation [here](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator).

This are screenshots of how it looks:

[image]
[image]

I tried using:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But neither seems to have any effect on the layout.

This is my Activities XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="aris.projectaris.InfoPreviewActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_info_preview" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what does `hierarchyviewer` / [layout inspector](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector) show?

Comment: Well, it shows a toolbar on top. I'm pretty sure it's the one that should be there (the not-empty one). I updated the question with my activity xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the default `ActionBar` is still there even though you have added a `Toolbar`. Make sure to set on of the following themes

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

in the `<application>` or appropriate `<activity>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**EDIT:**

If you use one of these themes, you must set up the Toolbar as the app bar in the `onCreate` method of the Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(t);
}
```

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Yet, it doesn't work. The themes seem to only change **both** bar's background color, but they are still there.

Comment: Do you think getting the ActionBar View is possible? Maybe setting it's visibility to **View.GONE** works.

Comment: Anyway, why are you not using the [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) around the Toolbar?

Comment: A reference to the ActionBar can be obtained in the Activity with `getActionBar()`.

Comment: What do you mean "around the Toolbar"?

Comment: That's weird, `getActionBar()` and `getSupportActionBar()` both return `null`

Comment: As a child element of AppBarLayout and parent element of Toolbar.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129286/discussion-between-pablo-kvitca-and-weibeld).